# How to offload computation to openstack(via devstack) installation in virtualbox?

Tags: java, android, linux, openstack, openstack-nova

I have an OpenStack installation in my laptop running in VirtualBox windows. I want to access it from my android client and send some computational queries and retrieve the response. I know all about hotspot and networking, Just tell me about the OpenStack setup part and how the client will connect to it i.e. GET/POST requests or sockets,  etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Senol has given you links to documentation for the OpenStack "control plane" APIs.  You would use these if you wanted to *programatically* do things like spin up new VMs, configure security groups, create and attach volumes and so on.

But if you want to do a computational task (say) on an existing OpenStack instance that you created on your DevStack installation ... that's software you need to put together yourself.  Basically, you setup something on your instance that can accept requests over its private network.  That could be via HTTP / HTTPS requests, or via SSH connections, or ... basically anything that can accept TCP connections, UDP packets and so on.

In short:

1. Set up OpenStack instance, networking, etc.
2. Install network capable software stack on instance.
3. Implement your application "service" to do your compute.

In your case, you appear to want your OpenStack instance to be accessible from the outside.  Therefore it either needs a public IP (that your Android client can route to) or you need to do some port forwarding from your laptop's IP / ports to the OpenStack instance's ports on its private network.  (This is getting "too broad" ...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've been looking for OpenStack api information. You can reach its APIs by cURL, Openstack Cli, REST clients or OpenStack SDK.

The [OpenStack API Documentation](https://developer.openstack.org/api-guide/quick-start/#api-quick-start-examples) can be a good starting point.